# How to binding content of listviewitem in listview?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing like the red zone

[image]

I have a problem. I want when I select the item it will change color. but my button don't show content. I don't know how to bind content from listviewitem? is this my way valid?

[image: image when running the code below]

This is my code:

```
  <ListView x:Name="lsvMenuItem" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding}" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Border  Background="Transparent" >
                                    <Button  x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding Path=ListViewItem.Cotent,ElementName=lsvMenuItem}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="button"  Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <ListViewItem>
                <Button Background="#FFC1D2F4" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Blue" Content="1"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <Button Background="#FFC1D2F4" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Blue" Content="2"/>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <Button Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Blue"   Content="3"  Width="40" />
            </ListViewItem>


        </ListView>
```

### Edit

When I have not used the template code (ListView.ItemContainerStyle)

[image]

When I use the template code

[image: Image 2]

I want when I use the template code, it will show content 1 2 3.

Comment: As a note, `<Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding}"/>` is entirely redundant. It sets the DataContext property to the value that it already has. That said, is `DisplayData` supposed to be a property of a data item class, where you have multiple instances?

Comment: What mutiliple instances? i don't understand what you mean.i can only do that.  I have just learned wpf.  Can you solve the problem help me?

Comment: No idea, it's hard to understand what you are trying to do. So what is `DisplayData`?

Comment: I'm sorry. I took the wrong code. i will edit.

Comment: i want to show " 1 , 2 ,3 " to 3 buttons in the image above

Comment: Do you just want the three buttons always? Are you showing us that picture because you're reproducing that paging mechanism or just for the little bit at the bottom? Ie is part of your question how to do the paging?

Comment: Andy. No. I just want when the button is seletec. it will change the background color. My code may change colors but hide content.

Comment: I have updated the description. I hope everyone helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are trying to get the ListViewItem content (which is a button) in your case and bind to a button's content, which is failing to work. The simplest approach for your problem is to bind ItemsSource from code-behind or from your ViewModel (in case if you are following MVVM pattern).

Here is my modified xaml and code -

```
<ListView x:Name="lsvMenuItem" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <Border Background="Transparent" x:Name="MainBorder">
                                <Button x:Name="button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Blue"
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False" Width="50" BorderThickness="0"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="MainBorder"  Property="Background" Value="#3d94fb"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="button"  Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="button"  Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="MainBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

And in code-behind I am binding ItemsSource of lsvMenuItem like below,

```
lsvMenuItem.ItemsSource = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
```

Note:- I have added "Foreground="Blue"" property to the Button inside your ControlTemplate itself.

Hope this helps. If any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: ok thank. How can i design similar to the picture at the top.

Comment: I have updated my answer (xaml code) as per the first image. I hope you can figure out rest. If it answers your basic question then please accept the answer.

Comment: To create a complete control of pagination, you should research a little on your own on how to do it and then come here to ask questions. We all here to help.

Comment: I want hide "1". i have to do it?

Comment: I did not get your question @DevilNight.

Comment: You have no idea how many hours I have been trying to get this to work and getting tangled up in templates of every kind (how many are there anyway?). This example saved my sanity. Thank you.